# Is it possible for one Java native agent to access symbols exposed by another Java native agent?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jvmti

I have two Java native agents to be used via the "-agentpath" argument and I want to share some state via global variables between these two native agents. If I export a global variable in one native agent, can it be accessed by the other native agent? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

FYI, wrapping the shared global variables in another shared library (.so) file solved my problem.